# Proguard generics return error when I try to convert <T> / generics

Tags: java, generics, proguard

I have this method 
`public <T> T getQuantity (int x );`

In proguard file , the line is 
`public ***T getQuantity (int );`

However I have trouble putting this in the pro file (proguard). I got this error

`Error: Expecting opening '(' or separator ';' before 'getQuantity' in line 104 of file 'conver.pro',
included from argument number 1`

How do i resolve this ? Thanks

Comment: I have solved this.